# Sencha app.json CSS

Tags: sencha-cmd

CAn anyone explain the below app.json snippet regarding the CSS part.

```
app.json

"css": [
    {
        "path": "${build.out.css.path}",
        "bundle": true
    },
        {
            "path": "bootstrap.css",
            "bootstrap": true
        },
        {
             "path":"main.css"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `path` is path to css file. If `bundle` set to true, it means that this file will become container for content from other css files in production mode. If `bootstrap` set to true, this file will be used only in development mode.

Here is example `app.json` file with detailed explanations: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/app_json.html